# Fix Groupby Length in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a grouped by Pandas dataframe:

```
id    date    temperature
1  2011-9-12   12
   2011-9-18   12
   2011-9-19   12
2  2011-9-12   15
3  2011-9-12   15
   2011-9-16   15
```

Here, each id has different numbers of records of temperature.

I want to fix them, to say the average number of records per id (say 3). If some records are missing I want to put zeros initially.

i.e. My final dataframe should be:

```
id    temperature
1     12
      12
      12
2     0
      0
      15
3     0
3     15
3     15
```

I need to customize the number of records per id to some number, which could be average number of records per id as well. How to get the average as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just using `stack` and `unstack`

```
df.groupby(level=0)['temperature'].\
      apply(list).\
         apply(pd.Series).iloc[:,:3].\
                 apply(lambda x : pd.Series(sorted(x,key=pd.notnull)),1).\
                   fillna(0).stack().reset_index(level=0)
Out[523]: 
   id     0
0   1  12.0
1   1  12.0
2   1  12.0
0   2   0.0
1   2   0.0
2   2  15.0
0   3   0.0
1   3  15.0
2   3  15.0
```

---

Numpy solution for speed up

```
s=df.groupby(level=0)['temperature'].apply(list)
s1=s.tolist()
arr = np.zeros((len(s1),3),int)
lens = [3-len(l) for l in s1]
mask = np.arange(3) >=np.array(lens)[:,None]
arr[mask] = np.concatenate(s1)
pd.DataFrame({'id':s.index.repeat(3),'temperature':arr.ravel()})
```

Comment: thank you! how to control number of rows per id and also, the order of zeros is wrong..

Comment: @tstseby so your date here is meaningless ?

Comment: @Wen_ben yes, since i am adding zero records date is not required, i just want to make sure every id has same number of records

Comment: @tstseby have adding a numpy fast solution . :-)

Comment: thanks, I get ValueError: Numpy boolean array indeximg cannot assign input values to output values...

Comment: Numpy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 6000 input values to 12000 output values where the mask is true

Comment: @tstseby adding this `df=df.groupby(level=0).head(3)` before above

Comment: what does this statement do: arr[mask] = np.concatenate(s1) , how do elements of the datframe get copied? this statement is giving the error, any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `reindex` with `range(3)` while accessing the groupby elements.
After that we `sort_values` and set `NaN` as first position so we can `fillna` as 0.

```
df_new = pd.concat([
    d[['id', 'temperature']].reset_index(drop=True).reindex(range(3)).sort_values('id', na_position='first')
    for _, d in df.groupby('id')
], ignore_index=True)

df_new['id'].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
df_new['temperature'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

print(df_new)
    id  temperature
0  1.0         12.0
1  1.0         12.0
2  1.0         12.0
3  2.0          0.0
4  2.0          0.0
5  2.0         15.0
6  3.0          0.0
7  3.0         15.0
8  3.0         15.0
```

**Note** you have `id` and `date` as index, so first run:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```